# MSAccess: FTP File Hanging Open?

Tags: ms-access, ftp, vba

I am seeing a new oddity in an FTP module I've used for a few years.

Task:

1. Export an Access Table as XLS
2. FTP the XLS to my FTP site
3. Launch a Stored Procedure to insert the XLS into a SQL table
4. Delete FTP file

Issue:  Recently the SP is returning a "0" (fail) when the function is run within quick succession (i.e., within 1-2 seconds).  My DBA reports the error as "7303" which seems to suggest the SP cannot grab the XLS file as it is locked OPEN (?)

If I put an arbitrary WAIT of like 5 seconds after the FTP complete before the SP is run, seems to be OK.

Question:  Is there any way to force the file to be unlocked/closed sooner?

Here's the FTP function (not mine):

```
Sub myFTP(Filename As String)  

Dim INet As Long
Dim INetConn As Long

Dim hostFile As String
Dim localFile As String
Dim Password As String
Dim RetVal As Long
Dim serverName As String
Dim Success As Long
Dim Username As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim intReply As Integer

Const BINARY_TRANSFER = 2

serverName = "<my ftp address>"
Username = "<my username>"
Password = "<my password>"

    strPath = Left(CurrentDb.NAME, InStrRev(CurrentDb.NAME, "\"))
    localFile = strPath & Filename
    hostFile = Mid(Filename, 1, Len(Filename) - 4) + "upload"

    RetVal = False
    INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1&, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)
    If INet > 0 Then
        INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, serverName, 0&, Username, Password, 1&, 0&, 0&)
        If INetConn > 0 Then
            Success = FtpPutFile(INetConn, localFile, hostFile, BINARY_TRANSFER, 0&)
            RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
        End If
        RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INet)
    End If

    If Success <> 0 Then
        'msgbox "FTP Upload Completed"
    Else
        MsgBox "FTP function failed"
    End If

err_Handler_Exit:

   Exit Sub

err_Handler:

    errMessage Err.Number, Err.Description
    Status "[FTP] - There was an FTP error - process stopped.", "Orange"
    Resume err_Handler_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like a problem with the server, not the client. You're moving the file to the server with a standard api call. FTP doesn't have any lock and release functionality in the protocol as far as I know. It's all at the discretion of the server.

Comment: Also, depending on the server setup, it might be a problem with a virus scanner. These might lock incoming files until they've been cleared.

Comment: Yes, figured that was the case, but thought "InternetCloseHandle" might have released the file immediately.  Seems like not quite the case.